# How to execute a last function when tkinter window gets closed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am designing a program and i want it to autosave when the root window gets closed by the user. I already created the function, but its not neccesary. How do i bind a function to the window close event?
[image]

Example code:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *



def main(*args):
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', root.destroy)
    global _top2, _w2
    _top2 = root
    _w2 = spiel(_top2)
    
    root.mainloop()




class spiel:
    def __init__(self, top=None):

        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        self.style = ttk.Style()

        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        top.geometry("600x450+475+21")
        top.minsize(600, 450)
        top.maxsize(600, 450)
        top.resizable(0,0)
        top.title("mathe")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.top = top
        self.Frame1 = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.Frame1.place(relx=0.017, rely=0.133, relheight=0.856
                          , relwidth=0.975)
        


def function():
    print(fr"This function shall be exectuted when the user closes the window.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Info:
I do not want to block the close button and create my own version using root.quit(), i want the user to have the normal close button.

If you know how to do this, please tell me, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `function` instead of `root.destroy` in `root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', ...)` and call `root.destroy()` at the end of `function()`:

```py
...

def function():
    print(fr"This function shall be exectuted when the user closes the window.")
    root.destroy()

def main(*args):
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', function) # call function() when window is closed
    global _top2, _w2
    _top2 = root
    _w2 = spiel(_top2)
    
    root.mainloop()

...
```

Comment: How about just overriding tkinter's `destroy` method in `spiel`

Comment: @demberto: Yes, it would to be possible to derive your `spiel` class from the `tkinter.Tk` class and override the inherited `destroy()` method.